# How to add a plotline to a bar chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add a plot line to a bar chart but it isn't showing up. All of the examples of plot lines I have found have to do with line charts but I don't see anything in the documentation that says plotlines don't work with bar. I tried adding the plotline when I initialized the chart and adding it after the fact and neither way works.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XmaN6/) is the example I am testing with.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 60,
            x: -60
        },
        plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 2,
                value: 80,
                zIndex: 5
            }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plotLines` is a sub-option of the [yAxis or xAxis config](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) and not a base option as you have it:

```
    <SNIP>
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 2,
                value: 80,
                zIndex: 5
            }]
    },
    <SNIP>
```

Update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XmaN6/1/).

[image]

Comment: In my actual code I had the plotLines underneath xAxis. I moved it to yAxis and now it's showing up. Thanks!

Comment: @chill182, yes, `bar` charts are drawn with the yAxis on the horizontal.

Answer (score 5):

Axis.addPlotLine() api allows to add a line in the axis after the chart has been rendered .

```
var plotOption = {

                color: '#FF0000',
                dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                width: 2,
                value: 1000,
                zIndex: 0,
                label : {
                    text : 'Goal'
                }
            };
this.lineChart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine(plotOption) ;
```

//where lineChart is the reference to the existing chart